# Comma Delimited Values in single cell parsed to new row

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize ahead of time as I am a VBA newbie. I have reviewed all of the posts regarding situations similar to mine and have not been able to come up with a solution. I have a spreadsheet with 9 columns (A:I) and 105,000 rows. Column F is a field that contains code(s). I can have a single code in there or up to 11 codes separated by a comma and then a space. I need to break out those multiple codes from column F into their own row with all other column data duplicated from the original row. For simplicity I am just going to sample 3 columns. Sorry for the formatting. Not sure how to make it a table.

1. FISCAL DATE - CPT CODES - SERVICE COUNT
2. 10/1/2013 - 36415 - 851
3. 9/1/2013 - 80051, 82565, 82947, 84520 - 220
4. 10/1/2013- 64523, 12214 (2) - 110
5. 10/1/2013 - *ERROR* - 12

Some rows may have *ERROR* for the CPT Code value or may also be blank. It's the way I receive the data.

I'd like the output to look like this. The "-" are only for the purpose of this post and are not acutally in the data.

1. FISCAL DATE - CPT CODES - SERVICE COUNT
2. 10/1/2013 - 36415 - 851
3. 9/1/2013 - 80051 - 220
4. 9/1/2013 - 82565 - 220
5. 9/1/2013 - 82947 - 220
6. 9/1/2013 - 84520 - 220
7. 10/1/2013- 64523 - 110
8. 10/1/2013- 12214 (2) - 110
9. 10/1/2013 - *ERROR* - 12

Keeping in mind that there are a total of 9 columns and that CPT Codes field is column F.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? Couldn't you just copy column F to a blank column (like J) and then do a text-to-columns with comma as the delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the cleanest way to do what I want but it works. I have to give thanks to another post for a portion of this code. Also, I apologize for not knowing how to format my posts.

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Find(What:=",", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Do
    Dim ans
    Dim Cels As Long, i As Long
    Cancel = True
    ans = Split(ActiveCell, ",")
    Cels = UBound(ans)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Resize(Cels).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, "A").Resize(Cels)
    For i = 0 To Cels
        ActiveCell.Offset(i) = Trim$(ans(i))
    Next

On Error GoTo Err
    Selection.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Err:
MsgBox "Macro Completed", vbOKOnly

End Sub